# Markov Chain upper bound on the probability of hitting time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I encountered the following problem.

- $\{x_t\}$: Markov chain in discrete time;
- $\Omega$: a finite state space s.t. $|\Omega|=n<\infty$;
- $\tau_w\equiv\min\{t\ge 0\,|\,x_t=w\}$, $w\in\Omega$ (first hitting time).

**Prove:**  For each $T\ge 1$ and every $x,y\in \Omega$
$$\Pr(\tau_y=T|x_0=x)\le\frac nT.$$

---

**Effort:** This is a surprising result as the setup is terribly general. I proceeded by induction. Using recursive characterization, we have
$$\Pr(\tau_y=T+1|x_0=x)=\sum_{z\ne y}\Pr(\tau_y=T|x_0=z)p(x,z),$$
where $p(x,z)=\Pr(x_{t+1}=x|x_t=z)$ is the transition probability. For each Markov chain, using the inductive hypothesis, we can easily confirm that this holds for $T$ sufficiently large. So far I cannot see how to show this for a general $T\ge n+1$.

Any hints or comments will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: this is wrong.

This seems incorrect.  Multiplying both sides by T and summing over T we get $ E( \tau  _y | x_0 =x) \leq n $.   I don't see why this should be true in general.

Comment: Please correct me if wrong. You meant that if the conclusion holds, we should necessarily have $T\Pr(\tau_y=T|x_0=x)\le n$ for each $T$. But when summing up the left-hand-side over $T$ to get expectation, we need also sum up the right-hand-side, which is the sum of infinitely many $n$, and thus is $\infty$, being true unconditionally. Would you clarify on this? Thanks!

Comment: @onol oops you're right,  what I wrote is nonsense

Comment: @AmichaiLampert Not a problem~ Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

I guess we can study the following quantity
$$f(T) = \max_{x \in \Omega} \mathbb{P}(\tau_y = T | x_0 = x).$$
This quantity satisfy two inequalities.

1. For any $T \geq 1$, $f(T) \leq f(T - 1)$.

Proof: It suffices to show, for any $x \in \Omega$, that
$$\mathbb{P}(\tau_y = T | x_0 = x) \leq f(T - 1).$$
If $x = y$, this is trivial since $\mathbb{P}(\tau_y = T | x_0 = x) = 0$. Otherwise, we run one step of the chain to obtain
$$\mathbb{P}(\tau_y = T | x_0 = x) = \sum_{x' \in \Omega} p(x, x') \mathbb{P}(\tau_y = T - 1 | x_0 = x') \leq \sum_{x' \in \Omega} p(x, x') f(T - 1) = f(T - 1)$$
as desired.

2. We have
   $$\sum_{T \geq 0} f(T) \leq |\Omega|.$$
   Proof: This comes from the observation that
   $$f(T) \leq \sum_{x \in \Omega} \mathbb{P}(\tau_y = T | x_0 = x).$$
   So
   $$\sum_{T \geq 0} f(T) \leq \sum_{x \in \Omega} \sum_{T \geq 0} \mathbb{P}(\tau_y = T | x_0 = x) = |\Omega|.$$
   Combining these two inequalities, we immediately obtain
   $$(T + 1) f(T) \leq \sum_{T \geq 0} f(T) \leq |\Omega|$$
   as desired.